# How do you make Dir.chdir in ruby to source or load a project .rvmrc file?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have several apps with tracked .rvmrc's in Git.

Problem is, I have this automated script which cd's to a specific app directory if given a certain switch.

Sadly, I cannot run any project related commands since it uses the default ruby and not the ruby specified on my project's .rvmrc file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load RVM into a shell session before "cd":

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then 
source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
elif [[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then   
source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
else
printf "ERROR: An RVM installation was not found.\n"
fi
```

http://beginrescueend.com/workflow/scripting/